# How can i calculate the sum of the grades in the marks list with for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

```
marks=[3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4]

d=len(marks)

s=0

for s in range(d):
    f=42/d
    print("The final grade:" + str(f))
```

Comment: Basicly i wanna find the final grade by divide the total marks by how many there were

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks on your code:

```
marks = [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4]

# this is OK, but you can just use len(marks), unless you want to save the value
d = len(marks)

# you initialise s, but that's not needed if you plan to use it as a loop variable
s=0

# you make s loop over the length of marks, but you can just loop over marks
for s in range(d):
    # this number appears out of nowhere, and you're dividing 42 by the length?
    f=42/d
    print("The final grade:" + str(f))
```

You were after:

```
marks = [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4]

number_of_marks = len(marks)

total = 0
for mark in marks:
    total += mark

result = total / number_of_marks 
print("The final grade:" + str(result))
```

But a simpler way to do the same:

```
marks = [3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4]

result = sum(marks) / len(marks)
print("The final grade:" + str(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
marks=[3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4]

ms = 0

for s in marks:
    ms+=s

f = ms/len(marks)

print("The final grade:" + str(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
marks=[3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4]

ms = 0

for s in marks:
ms+=s

f = ms/len(marks)

print("The final grade:" + str(f))

```py
print
```